# How to use pdftk in php while system functions is disabled

Tags: php, exec, pdftk

I want to use **pdftk** in my php code, like this:

```
<?php
  exec("pdftk myfile.pdf cat 1-3 output outfile_p1-3.pdf");
?>
```

But in the php.ini, we must limit the system functions like ***exec***.

> php.ini:
>
> `disable_functions = ln, cat, popen, ...., exec, ....`

How can I use **pdftk** along with ***exec*** in this situation?

I used some php libraries, like FPDF and TCPDF, but theses libraries is not work correctly for some special pdf files (some of pdfs built by LaTeX) while the system function **exec** works correctly.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: You either change the php.ini or use another tool to merge the pdf pages

Comment: "we must" needs some explaining on your part. If you purposefully disable executing system commends, then that's what you get. There's no built-in PHP functions for this.

Comment: we must, because for security issues. we can use some php library, like FPDF or TCPDF. But for some pdf files (generally built by LaTeX), these libraries is not work correctly!! I want some alternative solution, like open 'exec' function for an special folder, or use another server without limitation for system functions and present web services for using pdftk, or ....